# SQL Server rounding

Tags: sql-server, rounding, datediff

The DateDiff = 23 so 23/30 is 0.77.

I cannot get @Tenor to be 1, which is 0.77 rounded ... it keeps giving me 0 ...

```
DECLARE @Tenor Decimal(18,6)
SET     @Tenor =  ROUND(DATEDIFF(D,'2014-04-14','2014-05-07') / 30, 0)
```

It works if I do this ... this will give me 1. But I need to use the method above because it's all in an UPDATE statement. Tips appreciated, thanks.

```
DECLARE @Tenor Decimal(18,6)
DECLARE @dd decimal(18, 6)
SELECT @dd = DATEDIFF(D, '2014-04-14', '2014-05-07') 
SET @Tenor = Round(@dd/30,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `30.0` in your division to force non-integer arithmetic

```
DECLARE @Tenor Decimal(18,6)
SET     @Tenor =  ROUND(DATEDIFF(D,'2014-04-14','2014-05-07') / 30.0, 0)
SELECT  @Tenor -- 1.000000
```

The behaviour you are seeing is as a result of implicit type conversion in SQL Server. Both the return type of `DATEDIFF(D,'2014-04-14','2014-05-07')` and `30` are `int`, so integer division will occur when dividing the two (effectively removing the fractional part of the result, i.e. `0`).

In your second attempt the dividend (`@dd`) is defined as `decimal` which results an implicit cast of the divisor (`30`) to `decimal`, giving the result you'd expect.

Comment: thank you. That was pretty dang frustrating and would never think 30.0 would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @Tenor =  ROUND((CAST(DATEDIFF(D,'2014-04-14','2014-05-07') AS DECIMAL(18,6)) / 30), 0)
```

This should work to round it to 1.

Comment: actually, looking at it again, I do not want to use Ceiling ... but the casting to Decimal part might work (w/o the Ceiling).

Comment: Yes, you're correct it does work without the CEILING. I updated my answer.